# ViewPropertyAnimator - animation wouldn't happen the first time

Tags: java, android, animation, viewpropertyanimator

I'm using the following code for a slide in / slide out toggle for an `AppBarLayout`.

```
public void showToolbar(boolean show) {
    if (appBar == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "showToolbar: Toolbar is null");
        return;
    }
    boolean toolbarShown = Utils.isViewVisible(appBar);
    Log.d(TAG, "showToolbar: shown:" +shown);
    boolean changed = (show != toolbarShown);
    if (changed) {
        if (show) {
            Log.d(TAG, "showToolbar: showing");
            appBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            appBar.animate()
                    .translationY(0)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                    .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                            appBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) { }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) { }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) { }
                    })
                    .start();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "showToolbar: hiding");
            appBar.animate()
                    .translationY(-toolbar.getBottom())
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                    .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) { }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                            appBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) { }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) { }
                    })
                    .start();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "showToolbar: no change");
    }
}
```

The animation works perfectly except for the first time `showToolbar(true)` is called to show the toolbar. The view just shows up without animation the first time. I have scoured the site and found similar questions but the solutions doesn't seem to be working for me.

It might be worth noting that this happens only when we want the `appBar` to be hidden first. My guess is that maybe for the animation to

**Update 1:**

```
public static boolean isViewVisible(View view) {
    if (View.VISIBLE == view.getVisibility()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

**Update 2**

I have removed `isViewWithinScreenBounds()` method because that check isn't really needed.

Comment: Can you please provide implementation of the following methods:
Utils.isViewWithinScreenBounds, Utils.isViewVisible

Comment: Maybe try to put showToolbar(true) in the onCreateOptionsMenu(..) method

Comment: @Rzodkiewka doesn't work. No change.

Comment: Do you really need to use this code ? Looks quite complicated for just slide in/out appbar

Comment: @Rzodkiewka Yes, I need to use this code. I have removed isViewWithinScreenBounds because it always returns true anyway. But rest of the code should stay. It's not that complex imho.

Comment: @BinoyBabu is your `View`'s visibility set to `View.GONE` before running the first animation?

Comment: No. View.INVISIBLE

Comment: @BinoyBabu, ok and what exactly happens when you call `showToolbar(true)` for the first time? the `View` just shows up without animation? or it doesn't show up at all?

Comment: @BartekLipinski The view just shows up without animation.

Comment: @BinoyBabu ok, and do you even set the initial `translationY` for hidden state?

Comment: Yes, I tried setting -`android:translationY="-56dp"` 56dp being the height of my toobar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124160/discussion-between-bartek-lipinski-and-binoy-babu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to set the initial values for `visibility` and `translationY`.

If you want your toolbar to be initially hidden and show up with the first animation, be sure to set `android:visibility="invisible"` and **NOT** `"gone"`, and negative `android:translationY` like `-56dp`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:translationY="-120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SOME TEXT HERE" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Activity code

```
@BindView(R.id.app_bar)
AppBarLayout appBar;
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animateToolbar(false); //Just for testing purpose - delay execute of function animateToolbar() for 4 seconds
        }
    }, 4000);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    animateToolbar(true);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void animateToolbar(boolean show) {

    if (show) {
        // As you can see in the xml layout initial position of the appBar is translated by its height to the top of the screen "-" sign
        // Slide int from out of the screen to initial position -> from -120 dp (height of the app bar, see xml) to 0 dp 
        appBar.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .setDuration(1000)
                .start(); 

    } else {
        // Slide out from initial position to the top of the screen -> from 0 dp to -120 dp (height of the app bar, see xml)
        appBar.animate()
                .translationY(-appBar.getHeight())
                .setDuration(1000)
                .start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing here.